# Why is there no Convert.toFloat() method?

Tags: c#

Why there is not exist method `Convert.ToFloat()`,C# has `ToDouble()`,`ToDecimal()`...
I want convert to float, which method can be used? (float)var?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

There is - but it's called `Convert.ToSingle()`. `float` is a C# alias for the `System.Single` type.

"Single" is the name for a float in the BCL. "float" is an alias provided by C#. There's a Convert.ToSingle() method, just like there's
Convert.ToInt32() instead of Convert.ToInt().

See this thread [Convert class](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/246254-convert-class)

(BTW - I didn't know this either, so I learned something new today :) )